# How to build a command block machine that only allows YOU to be in a certain cord

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i have been trying this:

*hopper clock on here* and then comparator

```
testfor @a[Dr_Weasel99!=DR_WEASEL99,r=5]
```

*then if player is found in my place* again, a comparator

```
/tp @p[Dr_Weasel99=!Dr_Weasel99] ~ 20 ~
```

*they should fall to their death no matter what because bedrock is replaced with water*

but idk.
im trying to make it when someone else comes in my place they will get teleported away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/kill @p[name=!DR_Weaasel99,x=(x-coord), y=(y-coord), z=(z-coord), r=(range)]
```

Comment: im in 1.5.2 and the kill command doesnt work in command blocks x<

Comment: you can swap the kill out for tp and teleport them like 200 blocks downward

Comment: http://prntscr.com/5ytayv in second block i put that